# python doing a count(order_id) and cumulative and sum

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, datetime-format

Trying to do a count(order_id) & sum of total sales by month .

| order_id | delivered_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 11:00:00 UTC | 233.12 |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 11:00:00 UTC | 200.00 |
| 3 | 2021-03-01 11:00:00 UTC | 400.00 |
| 4 | 2021-02-28 11:00:00 UTC | 120.00 |

i try coding

```
orders_df.assign(delivered_date = orders_df.dates.dt.strftime('%Y/%M'))
.groupby (delivered_date , count(order_id) ,amount) 
.sum()
```

But i get error . I do need help here as im still learning python for now

Im trying to achieve a result of

| delivered_date | count(order_id) | sum(amount) | cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 1 | 233.12 | 233.12 |
| 2021-02 | 2 | 320.00 | 553.12 |
| 2021-03 | 1 | 400.00 | 953.12 |

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, in datetime format you have to make sure that it's a dtatetime format than switch it :

```
orders_df.delivered_date=pd.to_datetime(orders_df.delivered_date).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

this will give you the result you want :

Next it depends on your preferences ,if you want to sum on them :

```
g = orders_df.groupby(['delivered_date'])['amount'].sum()
j = orders_df.groupby(['delivered_date']).size().to_frame('count')

df=pd.merge(g, j, left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You . How can i factor in cumulative amount ? Anyone has any idea ?